# Android fragment instantiator doesn't run before onCreateView

Tags: android, class

What I am trying to do is instantiate a new fragment using arguments to set the values that are used inside `onCreateView` from my MainActivity class.

**Fragment Class**

```
//package
//imports

public class LansFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_TEXT = "arg_text";

    public LansFragment() {
        super();
    }

    public static LansFragment newInstance(String lan) {

        LansFragment fragment = new LansFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_TEXT, lan);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lans, container, false);
        Bundle args = getArguments();

        if (args != null) {
            String lan = args.getString(ARG_TEXT);
            //do things using params
        } else {
            //blank params 
            //should have been set when instantiated from MainActivity?
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity Class**

```
//package
//imports

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         String data = "Some string";
         LansFragment testfragment = LansFragment.newInstance(data);
    }
```

**Problem**

There are two issues at the moment. The first issue is if I remove:
`LansFragment testfragment = LansFragment.newInstance(data);` then this fragment still runs anyway, is this due to the fragment being declared inside the `activity_main.xml`?

Secondly, more important issue - When I instantiate the class and pass parameters in, as I do in the example, they are never available inside  `onViewCreate` and instead always appear as `null`, what is causing this to happen?

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="app.stats.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <fragment xmlns:android=
        "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/lans_fragment"
        android:name="app.stats.LansFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_lans"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a fragment in your `xml` it's created with a default constructor.

Line `LansFragment testfragment = LansFragment.newInstance(data);` creates a new fragment, but it is not added to your layout nor does it affect the fragment defined in xml.

If you want to create a fragment with additional arguments, you have to add it using `FragmentManager` like:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
      .replace(R.layout.fragment_layout, testfragment).commit();
```

Where `R.layout.fragment_layout` is a container layout in your xml, usually FrameLayout, in your case simply replace your `<fragment ...` with:

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_layout "
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Note that if your fragment extends `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` you should replace `getFragmentManager()` with `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: Do I have to use `FrameLayout` because it's nicer having different xml files per fragment to separate the code out?

Comment: `FrameLayout` only serves as a container for you `fragment` and goes into your `activity` layout. `Fragment`s themselves may have any parent layout you want.